# Python - How to modify existing drop-down list in a document using Google Docs API?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a Google Docs document stored in a Google Drive folder.

This document contains new features from Google Docs like the drop-down list.

> [image]
>
> Here's an example of a drop-down list I use. It has 2 different
> options : "In-Person" and "Virtual". The second one is selected.

I am able to copy this drop-down list when I copy a document where it's already present. But I want to also be able to modify it using Python. I checked the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview?hl=fr) but there is nothing about these kind of lists. So I analyzed the JSON response returned by the original document but nothing in there. Even if I search for the term "In-Person", present in my drop-down, I cannot find it.

In the JSON, this is what I found at the corresponding index:

```json
{
  "startIndex": 433,
  "endIndex": 436,
  "content": [
    {
      "startIndex": 434,
      "endIndex": 436,
      "paragraph": {
        "elements": [
          {
            "startIndex": 434,
            "endIndex": 436,
            "textRun": {
              "content": "\ue907\n",
              "textStyle": {
                "foregroundColor": {
                  "color": {
                    "rgbColor": {
                      "red": 0.2627451,
                      "green": 0.2627451,
                      "blue": 0.2627451
                    }
                  }
                },
                "fontSize": {
                  "magnitude": 8,
                  "unit": "PT"
                },
                "weightedFontFamily": {
                  "fontFamily": "Inter",
                  "weight": 400
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "paragraphStyle": {
          "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
          "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "tableCellStyle": {
    "rowSpan": 1,
    "columnSpan": 1,
    "backgroundColor": {
      "color": {
        "rgbColor": {
          "red": 1,
          "green": 1,
          "blue": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "contentAlignment": "MIDDLE"
  }
}
```

Notice the "\ue907\n" Unicode that is originally not present in my document. I can see that there are 7 of these in my document as I have 7 drop-down. That's the only clue I have.

How can I use this to modify a drop-down using Google Docs API ? Is this even possible ? Should I use another tool to achieve that ? (Google App Scripts ?)

Answer (score 0):

**Inserting Smart Chips**

The drop-down list from Google Docs is basically a "Smart Chips". However as you might suggest, the official documentation from 2021 added the support to only three classes on August 23:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2021#august_23_2021

The only available App Script class that can support the smart chips would be those, you are correct about the content type being "content": "\ue907\n"

That is the closes available option to manage the Smart Chips and retrieve their information, however this one is also very limited as dicussed over the issue tracker page that was created requesting more options or more classes to manage the smart chips:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225584757

I would highly suggest to like it and provide a comment about your specific scenario and how none of these classes fulfill the required response or output for "Dropdowns" (other users mention the functionality being missing).

**References:**

- [Insert smart chips & building blocks in your Google Doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10710316)